Blender Rigify - Is it possible to reuse bones from different armature in new metarig?
I'm rigging my first character in blender using Rigify. The character is ripped from a game and thus came with an original armature. I've made a new human meta rig, but want to also keep some additional bones from the original armature for things like hair and clothing. I have joined the two armatures together, and followed any and all advice I've found so far on proper parenting, type-setting and what not, but the rig won't generate. So I'm wondering if there is some detail that I've missed, or if it simply refuses to work and I need to replace the bones with fresh Rigify samples. Mainly because I will be rigging a lot of characters and don't want to be replacing hundreds of bones unless I have to.
The bones I want to reuse are basically all bone chains of 3-12 bones. I have:

Deleted all the unwanted bones from the OG armature and joined it with the meta rig
Parented the innermost bone to the closes spine bone, keep offset
Selected the innermost bones to be basic.copy_chain
Left the rest of the bones without type
Made sure they are all parented properly along the chains
Renamed them in a name.number.L/R - format

But still I'm getting the "RIGIFY ERROR: Bone '(bone name)': Input to rig type must be a chain of 2 or more bones. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'" - error for all of the chains.
Am I missing something or is it just broken? If I have to replace all of the bones, what are some features that would makes this process quicker? (Placing, parenting, naming, etc.)
Thank you very much in advance!


There's a section in the Blender Manual on creating and customising the Rigify metarig here and CGDive has done a complete course on Rigify in Blender 4 with the part you probably want here.

basic.copy_chain Rigify type requires at minimum 2 CONNECTED parented bones, so a simple way to let you generate the rig is to select all bones that belong to the original rig, except thoose which are the first in the chain (and that own a Rigify Type), hold Alt Key and click the "Connected" property while in Edit Mode.
You can also consider a workflow in which you directly join the hair and others original bones to the already generated Rigify rig, parenting them to the ORG-spine - ORG-spine.006 serie.


Ahh that fixed it, thank you!! One more option learned, I was going mad!
